# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) finally fixed

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was configuring my local Ubuntu installation (14.04 LTS). I got this error while trying to run `apt-get`. I have seen many answer regarding this issue. None of a single answer solve my issue. So I have decided to post a question even many duplicates exists. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I know please see my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I post my answer without editing my question because most of us like me only see the answer section. So here how I fixed my issue:

I was using 2 terminal and I forgot that I was installing another software  while trying to run another `apt-get` (installing on Ubuntu Software Center will cause the same), so I wait until the installation completed. After that no error occurred.

If this is not one your case then you can follow other answer:

1. [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)
2. [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process/15436#15436)

Hope this will help others.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: Actually none of all other answers solved my issue. I added similar questions so that they might be helpful for others.

Comment: In that case you may want to un-accept or even delete your answer.

Comment: For those who are using a virtual machine via VirtualBox and Vagrant, simply restarting the VM did it for me - this may also apply if your host machine O.S is Ubuntu or other flavour of *nix... Vagrant machine is ubuntu/xenial from https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64.